# get only rows with max group value

Tags: postgresql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

for example, we have:

```
element | group_value | value
a       | 1           | 2000
a       | 2           | 1500
a       | 2           | 2500
b       | 1           | 1000
```

I'd like to return only last 3 records as those are the records with max group value for each element.

I know for a solution with subquery but is there an efficient one?

To clarify: for element 'a':

2 is highest group_value so it returns rows 2 and 3 > (and not the first row as it's group value is not highest),

for element 'b':

1 is > highest group_value so it returns row(s) 4

My (performance-vice not good) solution to the problem is:

```
select * 
from   x x1 
where (element, group_value) in (select   element, max(group_value) 
                                 from     x x2 
                                 where    x1.element = x2.element 
                                 group by x2.element)
```

Comment: add a table schema please

Comment: How is your present query inefficient?

Comment: This question already has all kinds of answers with different performance on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586781/postgresql-fetch-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-column

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First answer uses a CTE to select max(group_value) and then join with the table.

```
with maxgv as 
(
    select element, max(group_value) maxg
    from x
    group by element
)
select x.element, x.group_value, x.value
from   maxgv
inner join x
on         x.element = maxgv.element
and        x.group_value = maxgv.maxg
;
```

This one uses RANK() function:

```
with grp as 
 (
     select element, group_value, value,
            rank() over (partition by element order by element, group_value desc) rn
     from x
)
select element, group_value, value
from   grp
where  rn = 1;
```

Both returns the same result:

> ```
> | element | group_value | value |
> |---------|-------------|-------|
> | a       | 2           | 1500  |
> | a       | 2           | 2500  |
> | b       | 1           | 1000  |
> ```

*Rextester [here](http://rextester.com/DPOC58364)*

<sub>But, just to check and compare performance, we need the table schema. I don't know which index is using your current query.</sub>

Comment: in this case it should return all records as 3 for "b" and 2 for "a" are hights group values for "b" and "a" and no it does not limit to 3 it could return n records, just that those records are in the max value group for specific element